# How to linearize a max function in a constraint?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I have linear program that has constraint as follows:

$
\max(x,y) \geq 0
$

where $x$ and $y$ are variables.
How to linearize this inequality?
How to write this constraints in google or tools?

Comment: What is the context of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to enforce the disjunction $x \ge 0 \lor y \ge 0$.  Introduce binary variable $z$, and enforce
\begin{align}
z=0 &\implies x \ge 0 \\
z=1 &\implies y \ge 0
\end{align}
If your solver does not support indicator constraints, you can linearize via big-M:
\begin{align}
-x &\le M z \\
-y &\le M(1-z)
\end{align}